# Problems copy files to windows ce from windows 7

Tags: windows, file-io, windows-7, windows-ce, copy-paste

I'm having trouble copying binary files to a Windows CE computer from a Windows 7 64bit PC.  All I'm using is Window Explorer to connect to the Windows CE computer through ethernet.  The file size increases after the copy.  I've done this through Windows XP, through the same method (connecting to Windows CE through ethernet, using windows explorer), and the file size doesn't change.

When I open the files in a hex viewer initial portion of the file appear the same then the CE file has a large section of NULL characters the files match again after this followed by another section of NULL characters in the CE file. Then matching again for a while and then a complete jumbled up miss match on both ends.

I have also tried using the command prompt 'copy' command with the biniary option enabled. same issue.

Any ideas of how to copy this over (due to certain restrictions I'm not allowed to install 3rd party software to do the copy)

NEW INFO:
Attempted this with a basic txt file did not get the error inititially (text of file was 'test'). When I increased the size of the text file to 1 MB (text of file was 'testtest\n' over and over) the issue occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug afaik affects all versions beyond Windows 7 and Windows CE 5.0 (It is not present in Windows Embedded Compact 7). For me this happens for all files with a filesize > 32Kb.

## Workaround with zip

You can work around that bug by zipping the files you want to transfer and then unzip them directly to the network share.

## Workaround FTP

Another workaround is to stop using SMB and use FTP instead. This will also no longer require you to manually enable NTLM v1.0 on your Windows 7 and up machines.

Answer (score 0):

I know about some authentication issues between CE devices and Windows 7/Vista (and 8, I suppose) PCs.
http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/smb
But I suppose that you should experience issues only during the authentication phase (if the folder is password-protected), not during file transfers.
Are you 100% sure that no CE application is accessing the file while you are transferring it?

Comment: Tried setting the [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
LMCompatibilityLevel=dword:1 didn't fix the issue. Also can confirm that nothing is trying to access the file during the transfer (no other programs are running and did the copy from a fresh system start, also see this issue with other similar files that we have attempted to copy over so it's not specific to just this file)

Comment: I see that there were some updates to the SMB server:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779930
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2712419
Did you try to install the latest QFEs for the windows CE version you are running on your device?

Comment: The issue has been retired and we have gone with a alternative solution to the problem.